# outputting a result is much slower that just executing its function?

Tags: haskell, io, primes

we are doing the project euler challenges with Haskell. Currently we're at no 7 "find the 10001st prime number"
Now we have a simple filter algorithm, nothing fancy but the calculation time varies widely with how you call the function.

```
primes = filterPrime [2..]
  where filterPrime (p:xs) =
          p : filterPrime [x | x <- xs, x `mod` p /= 0]
```

when using ghci with `primes` and just stopping when you see the numbers go over 100000 or so it usually runs ~3 seconds or so
when using `primes !! 10001` we have significantly longer runtimes up to 20 or 25 seconds. Once the list is filled, you can call the 10001st element instantly both ways.

Does anyone have a good explanation on how this works or why it takes so long in the second method?

Comment: Which one takes longer? The reason it's quick after you've calculated a bunch of the list is that your inefficient algorithm doesn't have to run again.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. If I restart GHCi or reload with `:r` in between running the commands to clear out the memoized results it seems to take about the same time whether I use `primes` or `primes !! 10001`.

Comment: @dfeuer calling `primes !! 10001` took longer

Comment: @Noughtmare after testing i can't reproduce it on my second machine so it must be a problem on my side. I will close the thread  and troubleshoot omo.

Comment: As a rule, GHCi is very bad for any kind of performance testing. It uses a bytecode interpreter to run unoptimized code, which may behave very differently from code compiled with `-O` or `-O2`. You should look at packages like `tasty-bench` or perhaps `criterion` to write real benchmarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

local problem, needs own troubleshooting